# 'C:\Program' is not recognized error

Tags: ant, cmd, environment-variables

I `set ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\ant-1.8.0`
then try to build local host by *Weblogic*. 
*But, it gives me the following error:*

> C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I already tried putting quotes when defining the variable: `"ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\ant-1.8.0"`. but it is not working either, *it shows the following error message:*

> Files\ant-1.8.0""=="" was unexpected at this time.

I have been stuck here for the past few weeks. Iv'e googled it many times but I still cant resolve the problem.

Edited:

> dir c:\pro /x

didn't show the Progra~1 and Progra~2

Comment: Try "C:\Progra~1" or whatever dir C: /x shows as 8.3 filename

Comment: Instead of "ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\ant-1.8.0" try ANT_HOME="C:\Program Files\ant-1.8.0"

Comment: tried it but still not working

Answer (score 1):

`set "var=content"` is a good practice to avoid having unintended trailing spaces, but your error occures when using the value. There you need qoutes (that are not part of your variable content with the above syntax):

```
set "folder=c:\program Files"
dir %folder%
dir "%folder%"
```

the first `dir` will give you "file not found", because it tries to show you the contents of `c:\program` (which doesn't exist) plus the contents of `files` (which also doesn't exist). The second `dir` will show you successfully the contents of `"c:\program files"`

Answer (score 0):

Even current versions of Windows automatically create a second file name which adheres to the old 8.3 naming scheme which has been there since DOS was invented. This name does not contain a space character which makes it a good candidate to be used in scenarios like that described by you.

Unless this has been explicitly disabled you can show the alternative filenames. 
Open a dosbox and enter `dir C:\pro* /x`. The result will be similar to this:

[image: Windows 10 showing short filenames]

I ran this on a German Windows 10 Pro but the output will be identical on other versions of Windows.
You can see that for `C:\Program Files` Windows created an alternative name `C:\Progra~1`.

Comment: I ran this, but it only have Program Files version and not PROGRA~1

Comment: It would be interesting to know what `fsutil  8dot3name query` returns